# I was unable to display the default value in date field when i was trying to get the values from datepicker to that particular field

Tags: javascript, jquery

JQUERY CODE IN JS PAGE

```
$('.dob').datepicker({
   onSelect: function() {

    //I am getting the value here but unable to give default value to input field
  });
```

Comment: This is incomplete and unclear. Please edit your question.

Comment: Actually what my question was i was trying to get the values from date field in jQuery and i was getting the values but when i was trying to load the values in the date field i was unable to load default value.. may i know the solution

Comment: //JQUERY CODE IN JS PAGE

$('.dob').datepicker({
 

 onSelect: function() {
   
 //I am getting the value here but unable to give default value to input field
   
});

//HTML CODE
<input type='text' name="dob"  class='datepicker-here picker no-border-text dob' onclick="dob_save();"  placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" value="10/10/2010" >

Comment: i was unable to write the code in a proper way here